# Difference in Sequential And Parallel Hotspot

Tags: parallel-processing, distributed, distributed-computing

I am studying Parallel Computing exam, and i read that hotspot problem can happens both in parallel that sequential execution. But in the former it is more dangerous.

Now i hope to understand by simple examples a case of sequential and a parallel hotspot problem, and if possible the difference between them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "hotspot problem"?

Comment: When a there is an overhead in a part of memory because there is a lot of traffic.